# How to change host and retain email MX records

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I am changing servers for a client, but keeping the same domain. How do I ensure I don’t break email?

**Original DNS**
**Host Name, Type, TTL, Data**
example.com, A, 1 hour, xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
example.com, MX, 1 hour, 1.apsmx.l.google.com

**Changing to**
**Host Name, Type, TTL, Data**
example.com, A, 1 hour, yyy.yy.yyy.yyy
example.com, MX, 1 hour, 1.apsmx.l.google.com

Will this break email?

Comment: I don't think your question is sufficiently clear about what will change at what point, and what will remain unchanged, to give a good answer. Also, remember internet names are public by  nature, so not much point in [trying to hide any detail.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/)

Comment: If the website sends email and the domain has an SPF record, you may also need to update any references to the old hosting to include the new hosting.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're referring to moving to a new web server, although your question could use some clarifying details.

If my observation is correct, then changing the A record as in your example will not affect email.